# At $x=0$, shouldn't this function be $0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, calculator

function is $f(x)=2.3^{3x\ }-\ 4.3^{2x\ }+2.3^x$ (Dots mean multiply)

according to me, at $x=0$, $f(0)=2\times 1-4 \times 1 + 2\times 1=0$

But why does this graph says otherwise?[image]

Am I having a brain fade or This calculator needs to be abandoned?

Comment: Is your calculator interpreting the dots as decimals? I just made that mistake and quickly deleted my answer because I misread the question.

Comment: Looks fine to me here https://www.desmos.com/calculator/r1lzd9fur7

Comment: Note that the OP says dots mean to multiply.

Comment: Did you literally use dots (period/full stop)? Periods don't mean multiplication. I think that usage is only limited to a few places. The widely accepted symbol is the middle dot `\cdot` or the cross symbol `\times`.

Comment: NO, i used "*" for multiplication sign. desmose automatically made them into dots @Max

Comment: @helloworld112358 Your graph missed a 3 in the first exponent.

Comment: Back to OP's question, the calculator DID interpret the dots as decimals. The correct graph is the same as David's one: 
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/39fwfwy7yo

Comment: Same equation but different graphs. What's this sorcery? @AspiringMathematician

Comment: @AspiringMathematician Thanks. Fixed. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cunwbnpeze

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you may have plotted the function incorrectly.

[image: Correct plot]

Comment: Funny, I typed in the same in desmos but gave me different graph

Comment: You can never have too many parentheses when using graphing calculator or plotting software, imo

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
\begin{align*}
f(x) = 2\cdot 3^{3x} - 4\cdot 3^{2x} + 2\cdot 3^{x} & = 2\cdot(3^{x})^{3} - 4\cdot(3^{x})^{2} + 2\cdot 3^{x} = 2\cdot 3^{x}[(3^{x})^{2} - 2\cdot 3^{x} + 1]\\
&= 2\cdot 3^{x}(3^{x}-1)^{2} 
\end{align*}

Therefore $f(x) = 0$ iff $3^{x} - 1 = 0$, which means you are right.